# Android - Last view in RelativeLayout disappears

Tags: android, gridview, layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

i want to display in a fragment 1 button, below this one gridView below which we have another button.

Everything is wrapped in a RelativeLayout like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gridview_bouton_new"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/creer_categorie"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></Button>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridview_bouton_new">
</GridView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gridview_bouton_valider"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/valider"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></Button>
```

It works fine until i have many items in the gridView. 
Above 6 rows the fragment get vertically scrollable but the last button disappears !

I tried to nest everything in a ScrollView but only the first row is displayed....

If anyone has the solution it would be very helpful !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using RecyclerView for this purpose: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

GridView is deprecated now and is not recommended to use. Also it is pretty limited.

RecyclerView, on the other hand, gives you ability to display as many items as you want **dynamically**.

You can also use GridLayoutManager to achieve desired grid look: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager

Answer (score 0):

You might Try LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout and use ScrollView as parent.